# Error serving HTML files from an Azure function

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to open, read and return an HTML files using Azure functions. I am developing locally and the logs says that the function executed successfully however on the browser I am getting 500 internal server error. Am I doing something wrong in here?

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const mime = require('../node_modules/mime-types');
module.exports = function (context, req) {
    const staticFilesFolder = 'www/build/';
    const defaultPage = 'index.html';
    getFile(context, req.query.file);
    function getFile(context, file) {
        const homeLocation = process.env["HOME"];
        if(!file || file == null || file === undefined){
            context.done(null,{status:200,body:"<h1>Define a file</h1>",headers:{
                "Content-Type":" text/html; charset=utf-8"
            }});
        }
        fs.readFile(path.resolve(path.join(homeLocation, staticFilesFolder, file)),
             (err, htmlContent) => {
                if (err) {
                    getFile(context, "404.html");
                }
                else {
                    const res = {
                        status: 200,
                        body: htmlContent,
                        headers:{
                            "Content-Type": mime.lookup(path.join(homeLocation, staticFilesFolder, file))
                        }

                    }
                    context.done(null,res);
                }
            })
    }

};
```

**Note**
I am sure that 404.html exists and index.html exists. When I log the contents of `htmlContent` it is giving the correct output.

functions.json

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods":["get"],
      "route":"home",
      "name": "req"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

Response on Chrome

[image: Response on Chrome with "Content-Length"]

If I removed "Content-Length" header the status code changes to 406.

[image: Response on Chrome without "Content-Length"]

**Update 1** The code seems to be running normally on Azure Portal but it is not working when running it locally.

Comment: Just tried your code and it works fine for me (locally/azure). Did you try to deploy it to azure?

Comment: Just tried it on Azure Portal and it's working fine. However it's still not working locally for some reason.

Comment: What is "index.html" content? Do local errors have messages (Response tab in chrome "network" tool)?

Comment: An HTML file generated from create-react-app. I modified the setting content-type in headers to be based on the file sent. I will update the question now.

Comment: Also, local errors don't have anything in the response tab, unfortunately. Worthy to mention is that if I deleted the headers object, I am able to see the content of the HTML file in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are combining two methods of returning data from an http triggered function(`context.res` and `context.done()`): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#accessing-the-request-and-response

Since you are using `context.res`, try removing `context.done();`

Comment: Thanks but removing context.done(); makes the function run indefinitely. I also tried using context.done(null,res) and setting "name" property in the output binding to "$return" and I get the same result as I stated in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You are making an incorrect use of `context.res`, you shouldn't be overwriting it but instead leveraging the methods provided by the Response class provided in the Azure NodeJS worker. If you are using using VSCode you'll get intellisense for these methods. Otherwise see: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-nodejs-worker/blob/dev/src/http/Response.ts

Your code should look something like this instead.

```
context.res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
context.res.raw(htmlContent)
```

Using `context.res.raw` or `context.res.send` will already perform the  `context.done` call for you.

<s>Make sure you use `content-type=text/html; charset-utf8` instead of `content-type=text/html` or you'll trigger an issue with the returned content-type. Instead of returning `content-type=text/html` you end up getting `content-type=text/plain` which will fail to render your html.</s>

Addressed on: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/2053